# MySQL - PHP Select - doesn't show diacritics

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to `SELECT` elements from a database. This database uses the UTF-8 encoding.

For example, in one column named `title`, I have a row with this text: `Crăciunul`. It appears fine in phpMyAdmin as `Crăciunul`.

Now, I'm trying to connect to database in PHP and SELECT this database element. The problem is that it appears as `Cr?ciunul` on my website, which has the UTF-8 encoding setted, too.

This problem appears only if I get elements form database. I have made a string in PHP = `Crăciunul`, and it is shown fine on the website.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:**

```
$con = mysql_connect("HOST","USER","PASS");

mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

if (mysql_errno($con) !== 0)
  {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
  }
if (!mysql_select_db("DB"))
  {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Comment: Does the column `title` use UTF-8 encoding too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set the character encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) of the DB connection.

```
$con = mysql_connect("HOST","USER","PASS");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

Also, please don't use this [deprecated `mysql` API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for new development.

Answer (score 2):

try this ...

place this code before executing query ...

```
mysqli_set_charset ($dbconnection, "utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');
```

and

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"UTF8");
```